# 会員制サービスにおける、詳細なアクセス制御機能の実装

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP2において会員制サービスを作ろうとしています。

actionレベルでのアクセス制御はACLという機能で実装できるようなのですが、
更にその下のパラメータレベルでのアクセス制御の実装方法が分かりません。
お詳しい方、ご教示頂けないでしょうか。宜しくお願い致します。

想定しているのは以下のイメージです。
会員AとBがいて、Aは#1のみにアクセスでき、Bは#2のみにアクセスできる。

## 1：http://example.com/restaurants(controller)/edit(action)/1

(id=1のレストラン情報を修正)

## 2：http://example.com/restaurants(controller)/edit(action)/2

(id=2のレストラン情報を修正)

【環境】
・CakePHP2.5.6
・PHP5.5.30
・XSERVER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

アクション単位でのログイン制御だけであれば、authを使用する事で実現できます。
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

aclはユーザーを管理者などの権限をグループ分けし、権限グループのユーザーと対応するテーブルに対しての制御が可能なようです。
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html

URLのパラメーターに対する許可の機能はいづれもないと思われますので、ロジックで制御するしかないように思います。